# Why do we use inheritance in Java when one class can already access another class fields?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have two scenarios

1. Without Extending:

   class A
   {
   public void print()
   {
   System.out.println("Class A");
   }
   }

   class B
   {
   B()
   {
   A obj=new A();
   obj.print();
   }
   }

   public class Main
   {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   B obj=new B();
   }
   }
2. With inheritance:

   class A
   {
   public void print()
   {
   System.out.println("Class A");
   }
   }

   class B extends A
   {
   B()
   {
   A obj=new A();
   obj.print();
   }
   }

   public class Main
   {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   B obj=new B();
   }
   }

As both work as same then why do we need to extend another class?
And what is the key difference between both methods?

Comment: Think of the object as real objects and consider the relationship of "is_a" vs "has_a"  The Spaniel "is_a" dog.  The man "has_a" dog.

Comment: BTW `class B extends A { B() { A obj=new A(); obj.print(); } }` is incorrect.  Class B should not instantiate `A` because it already "is_a" A.

Comment: So that you can have a variable that can reference either an `A` or a `B`.